# Power of Dhritarashtra(धृतराष्ट्र)

Tags: mahabharata

How does he get so much power that he can even break Bhima(or a statue) into pieces in Mahabharat after Pandavs wins againt Kouravas.

- Who gave him that power?(I am not sure but I heard that he got 1000 Elephant power)
- How much Power he had?

Comment: I have read this some where i will answer tomorrow

Comment: I am waiting bro(or sir)..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This section of the **Sambhava Parva**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01107.htm) in the **Adi-Parva of Mahabharata** narrates how/why Dhritarashtra had the power of 10,000 elephants.

It is known that Vyasa was the father of Dhritarashtra, Pandu and Vidura. After Vyasa begets a child on Ambalika, Satyavati asks him how the child will be and what accomplishments he will possess.

> The Rishi, from desire of accomplishing his mother's wishes, however
>   knew her. But the latter, struck with fear, opened not her eyes even
>   once to look at him.
>
> **And when Vyasa came out, he was met by his mother, who asked him,
>   'Shall the princess have an accomplished son?'**
>
> **Hearing her, he replied, 'The son of the princess she will bring forth
>   shall be equal in might unto ten thousand elephants.** He will be an
>   illustrious royal sage, possessed of great learning and intelligence
>   and energy. The high-souled one shall have in his time a century of
>   sons. But from the fault of his mother he shall be blind.'

So you could say that Vyasa gave this power to Dhritarashtra as a boon.